# Find command only works in current dir

Tags: linux, find

within the `~/Downloads` dir..

`cd ~/Downloads`

and running find:
`find ~/Downloads -name "*.zip"`

returns all the zips in that dir

```
./modules (7).zip
./CodeRunner-3.1.zip
./Flux.zip
......
```

But from another folder

`cd /`

and running the same command:

`find ~/Downloads -name "*.zip"`

returns nothing..

what is that?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Check if there's a `find` program in `/`. If you have `.` in your `$PATH`, it will run that program rather than the normal one.

Comment: Also, what does `type find` show?

Answer (score 0):

I might try a command like grep to search through a directory.

```
find ~/Downloads |grep -e "\.zip$"
```